# Why does R take a long time to run code metacommunity?

Tags: r

I am trying to run beta diversity analyses using the metacom package in R. I have a 61 variable by 36 object matrix (called: mydata_5RB_PA) and I am running the code metacommunity(). R runs the code but never finishes and therefore I never get any output.

My code is below:

`Metacommunity(comm=mydata_5RB_PA, scores=1, method='r1', sims=10)`

But using an example matrix that is only 20 variables by 20 objects from another package works:

```
data(TestMatrices)
intmat <- TestMatrices[[7]]
class(intmat)

#determines the elements of metacommunity structure
ems.test <- Metacommunity(intmat, method='r1', sims=100, scores=1)
ems.test
```

I have tried different methods of generating null matrices (method=) and lowered the number of simulated null matrices to use (sims=) but nothing is working.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! I have hit a wall!